# Determine number of rows in a List Box

Tags: user-interface, winapi

Does anybody know how I can find out the number of visible rows in a list box? I tried the following but it doesn't work because there can be a scrollbar at the bottom of the list box:

```
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r);    
visible_rows = (r.bottom - r.top) / SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETITEMHEIGHT, 0, 0);
```

Another idea of mine was to find out the index of the last visible item using `LB_ITEMFROMPOINT` and then subtract the index of the first visible item obtained via `LB_GETTOPINDEX`. But this will only work if the list box really has items at the top and bottom but I'm looking for a generic solution which also works with an empty list box.

So does anybody have any other suggestions how I could find out the number of visible rows in a list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the *window rectangle* which includes the control's non-client area (border and possible scrollbars). If you use `GetClientRect` instead then the scroll bar will already be removed from the calculation:

```
RECT r;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
visible_rows = (r.bottom - r.top) / SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETITEMHEIGHT, 0, 0);
```

This calculation also assumes the `LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT` style is not set; if it is you would need to take a possible partial last line into account as well.

Comment: And what if the ListBox does not contain enough items to fill the entire client area? This code tells you how many max items *CAN* fit in the visible area, not how many items *ACTUALLY* are visible.  A better solution would be to use `LB_GETTOPINDEX` to discover the index of the top-most visible item, then use this code to calculate the index of the bottom-most visible item, and then truncate that result as needed if it exceeds the value of `LB_GETCOUNT`

Comment: Yes, actually I did, and I stick by what I said.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I usually try to answer the question that was asked, rather than the question that I think should have been asked.

Comment: I read the original question as "visible rows" being equal to "visible items".  If the OP really means "rows" to be separate from "items", as in how many total items COULD fit within the client area if full, then your answer is right (assuming non-variable item heights). But if the OP really means "rows" to be equal to "items", then I stick by my answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau *"But this will only work if the list box really has items at the top and bottom but I'm looking for a generic solution which also works with an empty list box."* seems clear to me. An empty list box does not need a solution unless you want to know how many rows **could** fit in it.

Answer (score 0):

If your ListBox does not have the `LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` style, try something like this:

```
int visible_rows;

int count = SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
if (count > 0)
{
    int top_index = SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0);

    RECT r;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
    int max_visible_rows = (r.bottom - r.top) / SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETITEMHEIGHT, 0, 0);

    int bottom_index = (top_index + max_visible_rows) - 1;
    if (bottom_index >= count)
        bottom_index = count - 1;

    visible_rows = (last_index - top_index) + 1;
}
else
    visible_rows = 0;
```

However, if your ListBox has the `LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` style, you cannot use a single `LB_GETITEMHEIGHT` message to calculate the visible count, as each item may have a different height.  In which case, you will have to use something more like this instead:

```
int visible_rows = 0;

int count = SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
if (count > 0)
{
    int top_index = SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0);

    RECT r;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
    int client_height = r.bottom - r.top;

    for (int idx = top_index; (idx < count) && (client_height > 0); ++idx)
    {
         ++visible_rows;
         client_height -= SendMessage(hwnd, LB_GETITEMHEIGHT, idx, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this addresses the stated goal *"I'm looking for a generic solution which also works with an empty list box."*

Comment: Um, because in both approaches, I am checking for an empty list.  If empty, I set `visible_rows` to 0, otherwise I calculate the visible count. What is not apparent about that to you?

Comment: The OP wants to know how many rows could fit in the listbox regardless of the number of items in the listbox.

Comment: The OP's question DOES NOT make that distinction one way or the other. It is an ambiguous question in its current form. It can be interpreted either way. If the OP wants to clarify the question, great.  The OP already accepted your answer, but your answer was the only answer provided at the time. If that answer solves the OP's issue, so be it. I merely provided an alternative interpretation of the information provided. I don't think it warranted a downvote.

Comment: It doesn't seem ambiguous to me at all; everything the OP says he tried and the problems he had with his approach make that clear.